# Screen still scrolling randomly, when mouse is connected, even after running through fix checklist

Tags: mouse, windows-11, scrolling

I've got a brand new HP ENVY 17.3 inch Laptop PC 17-cr0000 with Windows 11 on it. I'm currently having to either disconnect my mouse and use the trackpad, or deal with random, extremely annoying bouts of scrolling (i think, mostly on browser, but I wouldn't swear to it).

I have made sure "Scroll inactive windows when hovering over them" is off, that Windows Update has nothing pending and that my mouse drivers are the latest.

I'd done 1, 2, and three of [this](https://www.guidingtech.com/top-ways-to-fix-unable-to-remove-bluetooth-device-on-windows-11/).

I've tried two different mice (is it mice for electronic devices?) on a different computer and they behave normally. Even though, to be sure, I ran "msdt.exe -id DeviceDiagnostic" and made sure to enable Windows to automatically install driver updates.

I am running out of ideas and it is still happening.

Comment: If this has been happening since you got the computer, the problem might be with the computer. Have you tried USB *and* PS/2 mouses? (I don't like "mice")

Comment: @harrymc Seems that the answer was in the mouse. I posted it, in case someone runs into this issue in the future.

Comment: Didn't you say you tried two mouses?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the mouse's batteries.
It's been a few hours now. It hasn't happened since... Mystery solved?